# Database connection error on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

vietphappro1@cloudshell:~/ShopMyPham/Selling (shopmypham-408215)$ cd '/home/vietphappro1/ShopMyPham/Selling' && '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:33001' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '@/tmp/cp_5ugrtiohpjvkyzq1sac2271fl.argfile' 'orishop.DAO.DBConnectionSQLServer'
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 34.87.119.19, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:231)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.convertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:282)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2578)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:719)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3523)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3172)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:3014)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1836)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1246)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
at orishop.DAO.DBConnectionSQLServer.getConnectionW(DBConnectionSQLServer.java:22)
at orishop.DAO.DBConnectionSQLServer.main(DBConnectionSQLServer.java:27)

I am trying to deploy my website to google app engine
I'm in the database connection phase, when I run it in eclipse it works normally, but when I upload it to google app engine it gives an error like that
hope everyone will help me
thank you very much

Comment: Dear Thanh,

Thanks for your post! I want to suggestion some guidance for formatting the post to get better help. Having a clear title and formatting the body of the post will encourage reviewers to assist and respond. Good luck:

Suggestions:

Update Title: "TCP/IP Connection Timeout Error with SQL Server on Google App Engine"

Body:

"I am deploying a Java-based website to Google App Engine and have encountered a database connection issue with SQL Server. It works fine locally in Eclipse, but I get a TCP/IP connection timeout error when deployed.

Error Summary:
SQLServerException: TCP/IP co